# Can two iphones connect over wifi without user interaction?

Tags: iphone

I'm working through an idea for an iphone app. One of the tech requirements I'm considering is the need to send a short data message to another iphone running the same application within range, but this would need to happen transparently.

I don't have 2 devices to test (yet, obviously I'll need them eventually), and haven't been able to find a definitive answer in the SDK docs, so I'm wondering if anyone knows - in principle, is it possible to connect to another iphone without user interaction? Assume both devices are running the application, and that the user is aware that this is expected behavior, and that I'm not doing anything sinister.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is the ability to broadcast a small piece of information without any user being aware of the peers involved. I've considered using a server to facilitate this, and that's a viable alternative, but the data is location and time sensitive, so peer-peer communication is more appropriate (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CocoaTouch/GameKit/index.html) and [`GKSession`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).